# Build iOS Xcode project on linux

Tags: ios, linux, xcode, build

I've been recently trying to build Xcode workspaces on a Linux machine using Facebook's [xcbuild](https://github.com/facebook/xcbuild) tool. But after successfully installing it in my Ubuntu 19.10 machine I faced this errors after running `xcbuild`:

```
error: couldn't find developer dir
error: couldn't create build environment
```

What should I do to mitigate these errors? Are there another way/tool to build iOS projects on Linux for TestFlight or Ad Hoc installation? (Storyboard support isn't necessary)

Comment: Same problem here. Did you get to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, no :/ . I ended setting a KVM based MacOS X virtual machine on the Linux server I mentioned in the question to run XCode builds.